# When do you use the 'tag-name' when instantiating Polymer

Tags: polymer

You instantiate Polymer

Polymer({})

but sometimes I see a tag-name specified

Polymer('tag-name',{})

When to use or not use tag-name when instantiating Polymer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in polymers api docs

Element registration
The Polymer method is used to register an element:

Polymer([ tag-name, ] [prototype]);
Where:

tag-name matches the name attribute in the  tag. tag-name is optional unless the script tag that calls Polymer is placed outside the  tag.

Comment: You got it. Usually you don't need it, as the Polymer library can infer the tag name from context, but in some cases it's impossible to infer.